# Get cell value from gridview and convert it into int

Tags: c#, gridview, int, datagridviewcolumn

I have a gridview, that has 4 columns, the first column has a select button, and I need to get the values of the fourth column, depending on which button do u press. And i need to get or convert the value of the fourth column into int. Thanks for the help!

My code is

```
int ci = Convert.ToInt32(grdClientes.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Cells[4].ToString()); 
List<int> listaTels = lgCliente.ListaTelefonos(ci);
```

Comment: First: When you ask questions here you should show some effort to solve your problem,not just ask us to write some code for you. Next: There is an event named _CellContentClick_ and the event receives the row and column index of the click. Finally there are many ways to convert a string to an integer. Look for example to Convert.ToInt32 and/or Int32.TryParse

Comment: sorry, this was my first question, but Im not asking anyone to write my code, the only problem I have is, that I`m trying to convert a cell value into an int, and i cant, this is what i have:

Comment: int ci = Convert.ToInt32(grdClientes.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Cells[4].ToString());
List<int> listaTels = lgCliente.ListaTelefonos(ci);

Comment: try like: `var row=grdClientes.CurrentRow;`   or `DataGridViewRow row = grdClientes.Rows[grdClientes.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex];` and then : `Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["4"].Value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close:

```
int ci = Convert.ToInt32(grdClientes.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Cells[4].Text); 
List<int> listaTels = lgCliente.ListaTelefonos(ci);
```

Also, I would suggest `int.TryParse` and use of var instead of List.

To make your code more readable, you can use this:

```
int currentRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); // Get the current row
```

Now you can use currentRowIndex to get cell text.